# how to shorten url by htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, str-replace

I have this .htaccess line:

```
RewriteRule ^forum_(.*).html forum.php?frm=$1 [L]
```

and I have this php line :

```
$url = str_ireplace('forum.php?frm=', 'forum_.html', $url);
```

but the url become like this:

```
forum_.html1
```

and I want the url to become like:

```
forum_1.html
```

how to do that??

the full .htaccess file :

```
    RewriteEngine On
# begin index Page Rewriting
RewriteRule ^index index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index.html index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index.htm index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^forum_(.*)\.html forum.php?frm=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^topics_(.*) thread.php?tpc=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tpcs_auth_(.*) tpcs.php?auth=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tpcs_rauth_(.*) tpcs.php?rauth=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^users_(.*) user.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^chat.html chat.php [L]
RewriteRule ^signup.html signup.php [L]
RewriteRule ^users.html users.php [L]
RewriteRule ^cp.html Upanel.php [L]
RewriteRule ^messages.html pm.php [L]
RewriteRule ^style=(.*) changetemplate.php?action=changestl&styleid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^lostpw.html lostpw.php [L]

# end
```

the full seo.php file:

```
    $seotp = $config->Cquery("site_seo");
if($seotp == 0)ob_start();

function change_links(){
global $seotp;
if($seotp == 0){
$contents = ob_get_contents();
$contents = rewrite($contents);
ob_end_clean();
echo $contents;
}
}

function rewrite($url){
global $seotp;
if($seotp == 0){
$url = str_ireplace('href="index.php', 'href="index.html', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('href="./index.php', 'href="./index.html', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('href="./forum.php?frm=', 'href="./forum_.html', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('forum.php?frm=', 'forum_.html', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('href="./thread.php?tpc=', 'href="./topics_', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('thread.php?tpc=', 'topics_', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('href="./user.php?id=', 'href="./users_', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('user.php?id=', 'users_', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('tpcs.php?auth=', 'tpcs_auth_', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('tpcs.php?rauth=', 'tpcs_rauth_', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('href="./tpcs.php?auth=', 'href="./tpcs_auth_', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('href="./tpcs.php?rauth=', 'href="./tpcs_rauth_', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('href="chat.php', 'href="chat.html', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('href="users.php', 'href="users.html', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('href="./users.php', 'href="./users.html', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('href="singup.php', 'href=".singup.html', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('href="./singup.php', 'href="./singup.html', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('href="./Upanel.php', 'href="./cp.html', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('href="Upanel.php', 'href="cp.html', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('href="./pm.php', 'href="./messages.html', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('href="pm.php', 'href="messages.html', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('href="./lostpw.php', 'href="./lostpw.html', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('href="lostpw.php', 'href="lostpw.html', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('href="./changetemplate.php?action=changestl&styleid=', 'href="./style=', $url);
$url = str_ireplace('href="changetemplate.php?action=changestl&styleid=', 'href="style=', $url);
return $url;
}
}
```

when calling function : `change_links();`

Comment: try this http://itura.net/training/26--useful-url-rewriting-examples-using-htaccess.html

Comment: @RakeshSharma --> great !! but what i should to replace in php code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use preg_replace:

```
$url = preg_replace('/forum.php\?frm=([0-9]+)/', 'forum_$1.html', $url);
```

The use of a Regexp will solve your problem.

Comment: when I used preg_replace the script stopped and become just white page

Comment: Do you have the PCRE extension installed?

Comment: PCRE is the PHP extension to deal with regular expressions. It is installed by default on most servers...

Comment: the same result (white page)

Comment: i am using xampp server last version whit php 5.4.7 version

Comment: i think the extension not availabe for this version of php, the last version this table is 5.3.7 : http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.installation.php

Comment: Can you execute "phpinfo()" ?

Comment: does it say if you have PCRE extension available?

Comment: PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support-----------enabled

Comment: Try to enable PHP error messages and they'll give you some clue to find out the error